# Flutter | Load datatable after application load

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to load data table after application load. But when application load automatically data table also load. I need that data table load with button click event.

This is the primary widget.

**Widget build**

```
Container(
    child: OutlineButton(
        child: Text('UPDATE',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        color: Colors.orange,
        onPressed: () {abc();},
      ),
    ),
    itemCount==1 ? Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            activityHistory()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ):
```

I add that Data table to list view builder. I want to call that from button click.

**Called Datatable Widget**

```
    return ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          if (itemCount != 0) {
            print("OK");
            return Container(
                child:DataTable(

                  sortAscending: sort,
                  sortColumnIndex: 0,
                  columns: [
                    DataColumn(
                        label: Text("Code", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                        numeric: false,
                        onSort: (columnIndex, ascending) {
                          setState(() {
                            sort = !sort;
                          });
                          onSortColum(columnIndex, ascending);
                        }),
                    DataColumn(
                      label: Text("QTY", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                      numeric: false,
                    ),
                  ],
                  rows: avengers
                      .map(
                        (avenger) => DataRow(
                        selected: selectedAvengers.contains(avenger),
                        cells: [
                          DataCell(
                            Text(avenger.name),
                            onTap: () {
                              print('Selected ${avenger.name}');
                            },
                          ),
                          DataCell(
                            Text(avenger.weapon),
                          ),
                        ]),
                  ).toList(),
                ),
            );
          }else {
            print("SizedBox");
            return SizedBox();
          }
        }
    );}
```

Now that Data table load with the application . But i want it load after application load with button click .

**How can i load that table after application load and button click event ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially button is NOT clicked - show SizedBox. When button is clicked we pass callback function to onPressed and show ListView.

```
setState(() {
   clicked = true;
});
```

Something like this.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool clicked = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Load list on click"),
      ),
      body: activityHistory(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: (){
          setState(() {
            clicked = true;
          });
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
      ),
    );
  }
  
  Widget activityHistory() {
    if (!clicked) return SizedBox();
    
    return ListView(
      children: [
        Text("Item 1"),
        Text("Item 2"),
        Text("Item 3"),
        Text("Item 4"),
        Text("Item 5"),
      ],
    ); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I fixed that issue with your solution.